# How to use Task on Action collection?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have some Action collection.
Each of the action in the collection must wait the action before him before he run 
for example ..

```
   List<Action> actionCollection = new List<Action>()
   {
          func1,
          func2,
          func3
   };
```

Now, i want to make all the Actions to run in Task - but Action1 ( func 1 ) must run befor Action2 ( func 2 )
And Action2 can't start before Action1 is finished.

How to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just iterate through the list of actions and execute each in sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Task ExecuteConsecutivelyAsync(IEnumerable<Action> actions) {
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate {
        foreach (var action in actions) {
            action();
        }
    });
}
```

You may want/need to call the `StartNew` overload that accepts TaskScheduler and pass in `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` in order to keep the tasks running on your UI thread. As it is above, it will tend to run on the threadpool.